# is it possible that my server doesnt like api v3?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Im not sure how but thats the only conclusion I can come to.

Ive been playing around with placing a marker at a distance along a route, I found Mike Willamsons epoly.js and some example files and started to play around with them but for some reason the exact same code doesnt work on my server.

eg

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_directions-waypoints_kmmarkersC.html

is a simple example that drops two markers at 2 different distances along the route.

I simply viewed source, copied the entire code and pasted it into an hmtl file on my server, taking care to create the scripts directory and drop v3_epoly.js into it.

As you can see below, my page however does everything except output those 2 important markers.

http://peg-web.me.uk/map/

Am I missing something fundamental?

I know, this forum isnt for the epoly.js add in but Im trying to establish if my problem is more fundamental ie related to javascript itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those marker icons are referenced with relative URLs, copy the icons onto your server, put them in the same relative location to the HTML page and they will appear.

Or change this line in the createMarker function:

icon: getMarkerImage(color),

To (comment the property out):

// icon: getMarkerImage(color),

(that will make them use the default marker icon)

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you and again a thousand thank you's. I knew it would be something really stupid but for some reason I didnt even think to look at how the marker was created.